# What do the 3 numbers mean in manual partitioning of HDD in Ubuntu preseed?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, automation, automated-install, preseed

I see in official documentation this:

```
#d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
#      boot-root ::                                            \
#              40 50 100 ext3                                  \
#                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
#                      method{ format } format{ }              \
#                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
#                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
#              .                                               \
```

What is this `40 50 100`? What do these numbers mean? What size will in `/boot` partition ? I have not found an explanation in the documentation? C

Answer (score 6):

The three numbers are minimum size, priority, and maximum size.

If there is enough disk space to create this partition and all the partitions with a higher priority value with their maximum sizes, and still enough to create all defined lower-priority partitions with at least their minimum sizes, then you'll get the maximum size.

Basically, `partman-auto` starts with taking the minimum sizes of all the partitions. If the disk is not big enough to satisfy them, the partitioning fails and installation stops there.

If the disk is at least big enough to implement the minimum sizes, then any remaining disk capacity is divided up between all the partitions, with a weighted distribution.  The weight for a given partition is its priority number minus its minimum size.  Any partitions that would be sized larger than their maximum size due to this divvying up of the extra capacity, will instead by set to their maximum size, and then the leftover capacity will again be divided in this way until either all of it is used up or all partitions are set to max capacity.  (See [description in the docs](https://github.com/xobs/debian-installer/blob/b5dd4532de9ad15e9122893a0f00cb7cea531b5e/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt#L289-L319) for the exact method used.)

Once the sizes are determined this way, `partman-auto` has found the right partition sizes and actually does the partitioning.

Ubuntu uses the same installer technology as Debian does, so here's as official documentation as it gets: https://github.com/xobs/debian-installer/blob/master/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt

Comment: but which size, will i see after installation process ?

Comment: I added a description of how `partman-auto` works to my answer.

Comment: Description isn't accurate; I've submitted an edit.  https://github.com/xobs/debian-installer/blob/b5dd4532de9ad15e9122893a0f00cb7cea531b5e/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt#L289-L319 has the correct description which I've summarized in my answer edit.

Comment: If you want ALL the gory details, the source code is https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/partman-auto/-/blob/master/lib/recipes.sh but be warned, it's not very easy to read.

Comment: Couple additional points I wondered about and learned by reading the code: Any priority number less than or equal to the minimum size results in that partition size never being greater than the minimum.  (So if you have a bunch of different large partitions with priorities of 10, 20, and 30, those numbers aren't doing anything at all.)  Except, regardless of the priority number, the final partition listed will be set to [remaining space on the disk](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/partman-auto/-/blob/ea7aba580c3d22f8a45cf52024264667f8fb6315/lib/auto-shared.sh#L209-213).